# How save my changes to database with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I was wondering if someone can help me in this case: I'm trying to save my changes to database, so I use a context, and I have `_tblcustomer` which is an object from my entity classes, here is my code:

```
private void BtnSaveCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CustomerMode == (int)CustomerModeOperaton.insert)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TxtCustomerName.Text) ||
            !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TxtLastName.Text) ||
            !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TxtCustomerCode.Text))
        {
            tblCustomer Customer = new tblCustomer();

            Customer.CustomerName = TxtCustomerName.Text.ToString();
            Customer.CustomerCode = Convert.ToInt32(TxtCustomerCode.Text);

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TxtCustomerAdress.Text))
            { 
                 Customer.CustomerAdresse = TxtCustomerAdress.Text.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                Customer.CustomerAdresse = null;
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TxtCustomerPhone.Text))
            { 
                 Customer.CustomerPhone = Convert.ToInt32(TxtCustomerPhone.Text); 
            }
            else
            {
                Customer.CustomerPhone = null;
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TxtCustomerCellphone.Text))
            {
                Customer.CustomerCellPhone = Convert.ToInt32(TxtCustomerCellphone.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                Customer.CustomerCellPhone = null;
            }

            Customer.CustomerLastName = TxtLastName.Text.ToString();
            Customer.CustomerID = Guid.NewGuid();
            Customer.rowguid = Guid.NewGuid();

            using (var Context = new FactorEntities())
            {
                Context.tblCustomers.Add(Customer);
                Context.SaveChanges();
            }

            MessageBox.Show("اطلاعات مشتری در سیستم ثبت شد");
            // status=1;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("نام مشتری و نام خانوادگی و کد مشتری باید پر شوند");
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        using (var context = new FactorEntities())
        {
            var CustomerDetaile = context.tblCustomers.Find(CustomerID);

            _tblCustomer = new tblCustomer();
            _tblCustomer.CustomerID = CustomerDetaile.CustomerID;
            _tblCustomer.CustomerName = TxtCustomerName.Text;
            _tblCustomer.CustomerLastName = TxtLastName.Text;
            _tblCustomer.CustomerCode = Convert.ToInt32(TxtCustomerCode.Text);
            _tblCustomer.CustomerAdresse = TxtCustomerAdress.Text;

            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        MessageBox.Show("اطلاعات در سیستم ثبت شد");
    }
}
```

Main part is here:

```
using (var context =new FactorEntities())
{
    var CustomerDetaile = context.tblCustomers.Find(CustomerID);
    _tblCustomer = new tblCustomer();
    _tblCustomer.CustomerID = CustomerDetaile.CustomerID;
    _tblCustomer.CustomerName = TxtCustomerName.Text;
    _tblCustomer.CustomerLastName = TxtLastName.Text;
    _tblCustomer.CustomerCode = Convert.ToInt32(TxtCustomerCode.Text);
    _tblCustomer.CustomerAdresse = TxtCustomerAdress.Text;

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

but I don't know why it does not save yet...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `context.SaveChanges();` should do it, no?

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet yes sir.. but it dose not work

Comment: "it does not work" what doesn't work? `context.SaveChanges` works. What error messages?

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet there is no error message, context.SaveChanges should save my changes to data base, for example I change Customer last name with this code _tblCustomer.CustomerLastName = TxtLastName.Text; but it dose not save in my data base

Comment: Il you want tu modify the last name, you should instead write CustomerDetaile.CustomerLastName = TxtLastName.Text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see anywhere you add the _tblCustomer object in the context, with something like in your "main part"

```
context.tblCustomers.Add(_tblCustomer);
```

If instead you want to modify an exiting object, you should write instead

```
CustomerDetaile.CustomerId = "the new id"
```

And now it will be saved.

What you are doing now, is creating a new customer, assigning its values and do nothing with it.

Comment: because I shouldn't use this code... I have this customer in my database so why I should add it again !? If I add I would faced with this error:Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tblCustomers'

Comment: In this case, you must modify the entity you took from the database, not creating a new one (I edited my answer)

Answer (score 0):

To save new object to database in this case you would need to use:

```
var obj = context.TableName.New();
  obj.Name = "BLA"; 
  obj.Salary = 32; 
  context.TableName.Add(obj);
  context.SaveChanges();
```

To edit existing object in the table:

```
var obj = context.TableName.Find(id); 
obj.Name = "BLA"; 
obj.Salary = 32; 
context.Entry(obj).State = EntryState.Modified; 
context.SaveChanges();
```

It always worked for me=) Apply this concept to your code and it may work.

Comment: I didn't get Entrystate ,what is Entrystate in my code?

Comment: Not in yours, just for future if you would want to change something in existing object you would have to type that.

Comment: Example, 
var obj = context.TableName.Find(id);
obj.Name = "BLA";
obj.Salary = 32;
context.Entry(obj).State = EntryState.Modified;
context.SaveChanges();

Answer (score 0):

I shouldn't make a new ... I have to write code for my select... I got it by @ChristianKouamé help here is my code:

```
using (var context =new FactorEntities())
                {
                   var CustomerDetaile= context.tblCustomers.Find(CustomerID);
                   CustomerDetaile.CustomerID = CustomerID;
                   if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TxtCustomerName.Text))
                   {
                       CustomerDetaile.CustomerName = TxtCustomerName.Text;

                   }


                   CustomerDetaile.CustomerLastName = TxtLastName.Text;
                   CustomerDetaile.CustomerAdresse = TxtCustomerAdress.Text;
                   CustomerDetaile.CustomerCellPhone = Convert.ToInt32(TxtCustomerCellphone.Text);
                   CustomerDetaile.CustomerCode = Convert.ToInt32(TxtCustomerCode.Text);
                   context.SaveChanges();
                }
```

thanks a lot.